# Реакт библиотека диаграмм с картинками на осях

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image: github chart]

Ищу либу с графиками, в которой можно релизовать что то похожее на то, что на картинке. Главная проблема в картинках на оси х вместо текста. Не нашел ни одной, которая давала бы задавать произвольное отображение на осях, дает редактировать и стилизовать только текст.

Подскажите, если кто сталкивался. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Такая диаграмма делается руками за час без всяких дополнительных библиотек.

Comment: Да, но изобретать свой велосипед когда есть куча либ для графиков - такое

Comment: Не надо тут ничего изобретать. Без библиотек сделать гораздо проще и лучше. Тут даже svg не нужен под столбцовые диаграммы.

Comment: Нужно будет еще 3-4 вида диаграмм использовать, они есть в любой либе, каждую из них ручками реализовывать плохая идея, либа здесь оправдана

Comment: Мы целый проект с кучей диаграмм делали - сначала взяли d3.js, а потом его почти отовсюду выпилили, средств ангуляра или реакта в сочетании с svg хватает с головой для всех диаграмм.